# Looking for a Copy (Preferably PDF) of ``On the Visible Monarchy'' by Rev. Nicholas Sanders, D.D

Tags: catholicism, papacy, reference-request, saint

I have been reading a book from the Library of St. Francis de Sales entitled ``The Catholic Controversy.''

https://archive.org/details/catholiccontrove00sain

In it, he makes mention of and references on several occasions a book written by the Rev. Nicholas Sanders, D.D. entitled ``On the Visible Monarchy.''

I have never been able to locate a copy of this book, though another work of his ``The Rise and Growth of the Anglican Schism'' is readily available online.

Would anyone know where I can obtain a copy (preferably PDF) of Sanders' ``Visible Monarchy'' book?

Thank you.

Comment: A Google search and a couple of clicks brings a [scan from the Vatican Library copy](https://gutenberg.beic.it/webclient/DeliveryManager?pid=13768833) but the quality leaves a little to be desired and it's hardly accessible [in a technical sense of *accessible*].

Comment: @Andrew Leach Thank you kindly. This is a lot more than I was able to come up with. The book is in Latin, which likely is the language the book was originally published in. It would be nice to know if there was ever an English translation of the book; but I guess that is an open question. Your efforts have helped me a lot. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Œuvres* (vol. 1): *Controverses*](https://archive.org/details/oeuvresdesaintfr01fran), [p. CXL](https://archive.org/details/oeuvresdesaintfr01fran/page/n148/mode/2up), cites it as:

> [Sanders Nicolas](https://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n50026682/), professeur de théologie à Louvain<sup>[professor of theology at Leuven]</sup> (1527-1583).
>      [*De visibili monarchi Ecclesiae libri octo*](https://books.google.com/books?id=67VEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP5)<sup>[*On the Visible Monarchy in Eight Books*]</sup>, Lovanii, 1571

There doesn't appear to be an English translation.

Comment: Thank you for providing these very helpful resources.